Help with finding the understanding generalized raising/lowering operators
I'm working on the following problem:
If $| \mu \rangle$ is the state of the highest weight, that is $\mu = \mu_1 + \mu_2$ of the adjoint representation of $SU(3)$, show that the states:
$$
|A\rangle = E_{-\alpha^1} E_{-\alpha^2}| \mu \rangle $$
and
$$
|B\rangle = E_{-\alpha^2} E_{-\alpha^1}| \mu \rangle
$$
are linearly independent. Hint: Calculate the matrix elements $\langle A|A\rangle, \langle B|B\rangle, \langle A|B\rangle$ and show that $|A\rangle$ and $|B\rangle$ are linearly dependent if and only if $\langle A|A\rangle\langle B|B\rangle = \langle A|B\rangle\langle B|A\rangle$.
I understand how showing the equation on the matrix elements in the hint not holding will prove linear independence, but I don't think I quite understand how the generalized lowering and raising operators work.
Here's my work, which has a discrepancy somewhere:
For root $ \pm (\alpha^1 + \alpha^2)$,
$$
[E_{\alpha^1}, E_{\alpha^2}] = E_{\alpha^1 + \alpha^2} \\
\implies |A\rangle \ = [E_{-\alpha^1}, E_{-\alpha^2}]|\mu\rangle + \ E_{-\alpha^2} E_{-\alpha^1}|\mu\rangle \\
= |A\rangle \ = NE_{-\alpha^1-\alpha^2}|\mu\rangle + \ |B\rangle
$$
for non-zero constant $N$. Similarly, $|B\rangle \ =  -[E_{-\alpha^1}, E_{-\alpha^2}]|\mu\rangle + \ |A\rangle \ = - N*E_{-\alpha^1-\alpha^2}|\mu\rangle + \ |A\rangle
$
And so carrying out the matrix elements gives
$$
\implies \langle A|A\rangle = (\langle B| + N^{\dagger}\langle\mu|E_{\alpha^1+\alpha^2})(N E_{-\alpha^1 - \alpha^2}|\mu\rangle + |B\rangle) = |N|^2 + \langle B|B\rangle + N(\langle B|A\rangle - \langle B|B\rangle) + N^\dagger (\langle B|B\rangle - \langle B|A\rangle)
$$
and similarly for $\langle B|B\rangle$ but with $A$ and $B$ interchanged. I think I need to assume that $N$ is complex. If not, these equations reduce to saying $\langle A|A\rangle = |N|^2 + \langle B|B\rangle, \langle B|B\rangle = |N|^2 + \langle A|A\rangle$ which would imply $N = 0$.
Where am I going wrong in my argument? Clearly in $SU(3)$ the zero root/weight is doubly degenerate; the wave functions for $\pi^0, \eta$ mesons and $\Sigma^0, \Lambda$ baryons have zero weights for their respective octet models.
I don't think I understand how the Cartan raising/lowering operators work.
